# MobileFirst 7.0 Console text encoding issue after installing latest iFix

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

After installing the latest patches of MobileFirst CLI (7.0.0.0-MFPF-CLI-IF201505211954.zip), the text displayed in MFP console is showing special characters .

[image]

Someone know how to correct this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems an error has occurred... Apologies for that.

Did you receive this iFix via an IBM support ticket? If yes, please request a newer build. Request for: 7.0.0.0-IF201505310841 - this should not contain this error that you're experiencing(!).